# crxde lite search not working

Tags: aem

New project is assigned to me. The CRXDE Lite search is not working. It is difficult for me to search the templates and components. Please help me, how to make the search work in CRXDE Lite.

PFA

[CRXDE Lite search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjJtG.jpg)

Comment: Can you actually see the resource tree in the view on the left hand side? Maybe the davex bundle is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You try to search by query in CRXde
Steps

1. goto crxde
2. click on Tools
3. click on Query
4. provide path where you want to search
5. enter search text in Text input
6. click on generate button
7. then click on Execute button

[image: PFA the visual]